# VueJs - using template strings inside the data function returns undefined

Tags: vuejs2

When I'm trying to use `Template strings` inside the `data` function in vuejs but, it always returns `undefined` any idea how to solve this ?

I was trying to make a `URL` for an `API` call dynamic

Cheers,

```
  data() {
    return {
      baseUrl: `https://example.com/api/json?key=${this.key}`,
      key: "IzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc"
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JavaScript issue.  If you run the following simple example in JavaScript you'll get a "is not defined" error (when running in strict mode).

```
{ a: `${b}`, b: "123" }
> VM246:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

You can't reference an adjacent variable ('key' in your example) in an object literal declaration.

You can use a Vue.je computed property for baseURL:

```
computed: {
  baseUrl() {
    return `https://example.com/api/json?key=${this.key}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm, appreciate. so just for knowledge when you mentioned " This is a JavaScript issue " how can I deal with it in `js` ?

Answer (score 0):

The data property cannot be made dynamic. Use a computed property like below:

```
computed: {
    baseUrl() {
        return `https://example.com/api/json?key=${this.key}`
    }
}
```